# int divide float in assembly

Tags: assembly, divide

[alghoritm](https://www.algoritmy.net/article/154/Shell-sort)

[code](http://pastebin.com/hFNNqC55)

I write implementation Shell sort in assemble. My problem is at end this code. I have number in EAX and I want do this. EAX=EAX/2,2

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

:/

Comment: I know, but when i want add my code. Error message thrown "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"

Comment: i add my code to link
I want divide in label else

Comment: Does it need to be exactly `2.2`? If `2.2069` is close enough you could achieve that with `imul eax, eax, 29` / `shr eax, 6`

Comment: _"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"_ That's a strong hint that you shouldn't post questions that consist only of a  code dump with a title, and that you should spend some time writing a better question.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read your code since you can't be bothered to even put it in your question.

---

An integer approximation is probably your best bet, see Michael's comment.  Otherwise do it with SSE:

```
cvtsi2ss   xmm0, eax
divss      xmm0, [a_float_constant]
cvtss2si   eax, xmm0
```

Use cvttss2si if you want truncation instead of round-to-nearest.

---

Or with x87:

`push eax`, `fld` 2.2 from a constant, `fdivr [rsp]`.  `st(0) = (double)eax/2.2`.  Don't forget to fix the stack when you're done.

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to the insn set manual.